# Using Maclaurin Series Expansion, expand $x\csc x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am asked to expand the following function using Maclaurin's Series Expansion Technique. However, the firsr derivative of the function $x \csc x$ at $x=0$ i.e, $f'(x)=x\csc x$ at $x=0$ is not defined. So, how am I supposed to proceed with the expansion?

Comment: They likely meant the obvious continuous extension, which has $f(0)=1$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you please clarify.

Comment: @SayanBose They likely meant $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=1$ like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+x-%3E0+D%5Bx+csc%28x%29%2C%7Bx%2C6%7D%5D)

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute the multiplicative inverse of a power series in
$$
\frac{x}{\sin x}=\frac1{1-\frac{x^2}6+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+...}=1+\frac{x^2}6+...
$$